# Order by column with value multi decimal points in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

See below these my table data:

[image]

I want result order by `main_module` as

```
1
2
3
3.1
3.2
3.2.1
3.2.2
3.3
3.4
4
4.1
4.1.1
4.2
```

Comment: @maSTAShuFu How can 3.11.2 be numeric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried an approach with the availability of the `.` in the string. Also I used [Gordon Linoff's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44306086/2451726) logic too.

```
SELECT main_module,
    (CASE DotLen WHEN 0 THEN main_module 
                 WHEN 1 THEN substring_index(substring_index(main_module, '.', 1), '.', -1) 
                 WHEN 2 THEN substring_index(substring_index(main_module, '.', 1), '.',  1) ELSE 0 END * 1 ) AS D1,
    (CASE DotLen WHEN 1 THEN substring_index(substring_index(main_module, '.', 2), '.', -1) 
                 WHEN 2 THEN substring_index(substring_index(main_module, '.', 2), '.', -1) ELSE 0 END * 1 ) AS D2,
    (CASE DotLen WHEN 2 THEN substring_index(substring_index(main_module, '.', 3), '.', -1) ELSE 0 END * 1 ) AS D3
FROM (
    SELECT  *, LENGTH(main_module) - LENGTH(REPLACE(main_module, '.', '')) AS DotLen
    FROM `NumericCheck`
) AS R
ORDER BY D1, D2, D3;
```

You can skip the calculated values from the select by adding another sub query.

For sample, I tried with two digit decimals too, it is working fine.

Working Demo: http://rextester.com/ONNX5810

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hack. However it should work for most cases that you're likely to encounter...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table (string VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('1'),
('2'),
('3'),
('3.1'),
('3.2'),
('3.2.1'),
('3.21.2'),
('3.3'),
('3.4'),
('4'),
('4.1'),
('4.1.1'),
('4.2');

SELECT *
  FROM my_table
 ORDER 
    BY INET_ATON(REPLACE(TRIM(RPAD(string,8,' 0')),' ','.'));

    +--------+
    | string |
    +--------+
    | 1      |
    | 2      |
    | 3      |
    | 3.1    |
    | 3.2    |
    | 3.2.1  |
    | 3.3    |
    | 3.4    |
    | 3.21.2 |
    | 4      |
    | 4.1    |
    | 4.1.1  |
    | 4.2    |
    +--------+
```

Comment: Can you please tell why `length` 8 is taken in `RPAD`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
order by substring_index(main_module, '.', 1) + 0,
         substring_index(substring_index(main_module, '.', 2), '.', -1) + 0,
         substring_index(substring_index(main_module, '.', 3), '.', -1) + 0
```

This extracts each number from the module and uses that for ordering.

Comment: awesome @gordan !! can you please share your idea /thought for this process

Comment: @ShaileshChauhan . . . How does it not work?  Can you provide more details?

Comment: @Gordon see result  : https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2547775/aac310e417ca58b0ab6a314e683e2d03

Comment: @Strawberry . . . If you want 3.1, 3.10, 3.11, 3.2, 3.3, . . .   I'm pretty sure that is not what the OP wants, although the sample results for the sort is incomplete (it doesn't even cover the data in the sample inputs).

Comment: Thank you very much for supporting.